# Awesome CSS Effect

Tags: javascript, css, animation, mouse, mouseover

[404 Page](https://github.com/404) or [500 Page](https://github.com/500)

Anyone have any idea how to do this sort of thing? The animation that moves with your mouse? Thanks for the correction, @Alin. Just a link to a tutorial would be nice.

EDIT: Just also learned it's the parallax effect. That should help.

Comment: What is https://github.com/sdfasdfsdf ?

Comment: He is probably referring to the animation in the 404 page. So the link is valid.

Comment: It's called a parallax effect, if that helps finding the right tutorial: http://forthelose.org/examples-of-and-how-to-do-the-css-parallax-effect

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The effect is accomplished with javascript, not just CSS.

The source code is on the page you linked to.

Have a look at jParallax, which makes it easy to implement the effect in a robust way on your own site:
http://stephband.info/parallax.html

Answer (score 0):

Guess you can always start by firing up [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and have a look at the source.

Comment: I don't think so. If he didn't think of using firebug himself I doubt he'll understand something from the source. He asked for a tutorial.